# Ascii Encoding Breaks MediaWiki Pretty URLs

Tags: php, http, url, mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki site with the following configuration for pretty URLs:

```
$wgSitename = "somewiki";
$wgScriptPath = "";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
# Added to "beautify" URLs
$wgArticlePath = "${wgScriptPath}/$1";
#$wgUsePathInfo = true; # This is not needed
```

I can reach

https://somewiki/index.php?title=foo%2Bbar

but not

https://somewiki/foo%2Bbar     <--- This gives a 404

This wiki is running in IIS in the cloud.  URLs without non-ASCII characters work fine.  E.g., I can reach

protocol//somewiki/hellowiki

and

protocol//somewiki/index.php?title=hellowiki

There must be a setting or configuration to allow the encoded non-ASCII characters to work.

Comment: See [Manual:Short URL](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL) and the [Redwerks ShortURL Builder](http://shorturls.redwerks.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  There was a specific problem with the + symbol (unrelated to the URI encoding):

http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/60/404-Error-in-IIS-7-when-using-a-Url-with-a-plus-sign-in-the-path